# Magento 2.3 replace the comma in the price with the currency symbol

Tags: magento2.3, price, catalog, currency, format

I want to replace the comma in the price with the currency symbol to display something like this .[image: price format]

Answer (score 0):

I have below a javascript solution that may help you. It will only work with currency where the currency code is before the value. I have it working on my local environment so it should definitely push you a bit further.

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {

    $('.price').each(function (index, elt) {
        var price = $(elt).html();
        var currency = price.substring(0,1);
        var value = price.substring(1);

        $(elt).html(value.replace('.', '<sup>'+currency+'</sup>'));
    });
}
```